# Does anybody know of a repository or resource that has all of the correct filenames for Tetris on PowerPC for macintosh System 7?

Tags: powerpc, classic-mac-os

Someone at my school brought in a functioning Macintosh Classic running System 7 today that he bought off of Ebay. We were looking around on the applications that were already loaded on it and didn't realize that the keyboard's space button was busted, and we accidently renamed a few of the files in the Tetris folder to a bunch of spaces.

The game still functions, but we would like to rename the files back to normal as the operating system would not let us undo the changes.

Many google searches have returned nothing, and I am wondering if anybody knows of a website or repository that would show the original file names for all of the game's files.